# get normal vector at a specific point in a curve in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

Is it posible to get the exact normal vector from a control point inside a curve? I know the evaluate node gives you the normal vector at a certain range of the curve length, but what if I want the normal vector at the precise location of the  control point?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can evaluate n points using the *Resolution Parameter Type* where n is the number of points your spline have. Now, get the normal at the index of the point you want as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: well it actually works this solution, feeding the evaluate spline node with the point amount will return the normals from a bunch of points EVENLY distributed along the spline. But what I really need is: how to get the normal vector from control points (the ones you can edit in the viewport). I managed to calculate the bisector using the handle vectors, but rotations are unstable, thats why I'm trying with the normals.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch This is what the node tree does, the points won't be "EVENLY" distributed because we are using the *Resolution* sampling method. Just try it.